# Android : Adding image in email

Tags: android, image, email

I want to add image in email, if I add the file from sdcard then its working fine as given below.

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file///sdcard/Images/thumb.jpg)"));
```

But I want to add the image from assest. I have tried so many pernutation and combination with uri.parse and uri.fromfile but nothing works, can anyone tel how exactly the path should be to add the file from assets. Its very urgent.

Answer (score 1):

isnt it?:

```
file:/// instead of file///
```

... you missed the "`:`"

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: can you please tel me exactly which method I should use to add image in email? I have used open() but its returning inputstream, I can add file or string in the uri.

Comment: ya true, it retuns InputStream, by someother way you can get FileDescriptor for asset file. I guess you should store it temporary (create temp file insdcard) using is & then use new tempfile to attach to e-mail (URI).. write back